# can props and state ever point to the same memory reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `getDerivedStateFromProps` to capture props in put them in to local state. Here is an example of what I am trying to do. Here is my state setup.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dataSource: [],
        sort: {
            column: "",
            descending: false,
        },
    };
}
```

Here is how I am using `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        if (props.sort !== state.sort) {
            const dataSource = sortData(props.dataSource, props.sort, props.sortRows);
            return {
                dataSource,
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The idea here is that `sort` object contains information about how to sort, things like which column to sort by as well as the direction are included.

Now in order to avoid sorting the data needlessly in the `render` method, I am capturing the sort settings and dropping them in state, and then the thought process is that I only sort my data if the sort settings have changed. I can determine if the settings have changed by comparing them to what I currently have in state.

My question is whether there is a chance that the value of `this.state.sort` and the value of `props.sort` will be the same, but they will still not be equal due to being in different places in memory. In other words, let's assume my component has some other props which have changed and the component renders again firing the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method, I wonder if my comparison would break here since `state` and `props` are always different objects.

Any clarity would be a huge help.

NOTE: I am aware the correct approach here is to not use `getDerivedStateFromProps`, but rather to memoize my props. I started down the wrong path here and for now want to continue this way for the sake of gaining a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

props.sort & state.sort in your example never be equals.

1) props and state can't point to one memory. Props are constructor parameters, so they came from outside of class object, while state is class property. They are totally different variables.

2) You can't compare tow JS Objects in by '==='. You must specify 'equals' or 'compare' function by yourself.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JSON.stringify` for this in order to compare two object, you can not compare object with simple `"="` operator, you have to choose either `JSON.stringify` or  do it with manually.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        if (JSON.stringify(props.sort) !== JSON.stringify(state.sort)) {
            const dataSource = sortData(props.dataSource, props.sort, props.sortRows);
            return {
                dataSource,
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
```